# How can I get my imageView to scroll horizontally as well as vertically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I have an image which contains text and displays fine in larger screen devices but on smaller screens the text cannot be read. I decided to use one size and scroll on the smaller screens. I used the code below to set both vertical scrolling and horizontal scrolling but it will only scroll vertically.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
    <HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="820px"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context=".CategoriesActivity">
.
.
.
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/termsImg"
                android:layout_width="450dp"
                android:layout_height="600dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/headerPanel"
                android:background="@drawable/screen1" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

The horizontal scrolling works on larger screens but not on 240 or 320 size screens.

What do I need to change to allow my imageView to scroll horizontally as well as vertically?

Comment: First of all you don't need xmlns:android declaration in every Xml tag It should be present just in ScrollView tag, i.e., the first parent should contain this line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/layout0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/layout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout3"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    <!-- Your ImageVIew -->
                </ImageVIew>
            </LinearLayout>

        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

But as you see, it seems very unefficient. You can solve your problem by scale your image view to a appropriate `scaleType` and using one `ScrollView`.